# how to expand typescript definition for nodejs module

Tags: node.js, typescript

I use nodejs module "ws" and install typings `typings i dt~ws`

```
import * as WebSocket from "ws";
function add(client:WebScoket){
  let cid = client.clientId;
}
```

I wanna to **Expand** `WebSocket` with property `clientId`,but I don't know how.

I has try write follow code in my definition file  `index.d.ts`

```
declare module "ws" {
    class WebSocket {
        ip: string;
        clientId: number;
        project: string;
    }
}
```

but ineffective

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using extending of websocket class and using it?

For example:

```
interface WebSocketWithCliendId extends WebSocket {
    clientId: string;
}
```

Comment: I has use this method,but all definition `WebSocket` from file of "ws" `index.d.ts`,need change to `WebSocketWithCliendId`.  
such as:   
```ws.on("connection",(client,req)=>{```
should write:  
```ws.on("connection",(client:WebSocketWithCliendId ,req)=>{```